# does nginx support tcp and http proxy on single instance?

Tags: nginx

I have a requirement where I have a single nginx instance to act as a VIP for http requests and also the mysql db cluster.

Is it possible to put the same configs under one host? TCP syntax looks different than the http. Please help me with some sample config which will work.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me.
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx/admin-guide/load-balancer/tcp-udp-load-balancer/

```
http {

  # http content

    }

        upstream servers{
           server server1;
           server server2 backup;
    }
}


stream {
    upstream mygroup {
        least_conn;
        server db_master:3309;
        server db_slave:3309;
    }
    server {
        listen        3309;
        proxy_pass    mygroup;
        proxy_timeout 5s;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1s;
    }
}
```